# Partitioning worries

Tags: windows, partitioning, multi-boot, linux-mint, kali-linux

So, my laptop currently runs a dual-boot of Windows 10 and Linux Mint. I want to add Kali to that list. I've got my USB set up and ready to roll, but when I went to partition my drive, I started to worry.

My hard drive currently looks like this:

[image: My hard drive. It looks a mess.]

I want to shrink my Windows C: drive (/dev/sda4) by around 20gb and then install Kali into that space. However, the free space I create will be between two NTFS, presumably Windows partitions. I know that where partitions are is almost as important as how big they are. Will this break anything?

My initial thought was to shift every other partition left, and install it at the end. However, I heard that that will (possibly) cause me to not be able to boot into one OS, the other, or both. Do I have to risk it?

In short: do I have to move the partitions leftwards and install at the end, or am I overreacting and I should just shrink C:, install Kali slap-bang in the centre of my hard drive and get on with my life?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackdafish, this is a good question. First of all, be very careful with this process because, YES, you can easily mess up your partition table.

And just to be safe, I'd back up my irreplaceable photos and documents. I'm not saying anything bad will happen, but I've lost a bunch very important stuff by doing this sort of thing. So I tend to be overly-cautions when performing these types of maneuvers.

If I were you, I'd resize the C drive and install Kali smack-dab in the middle. You're more likely to run into problems if you start moving partitions around.

Gparted does a good job of resizing partitions safely. So if you resize and then install Kali in the free space you'll be ok. Just as long as you don't accidentally overwrite the wrong partition during the install process.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll do that after school today and report back. :)

Comment: Success! Cheers!

Comment: Good Job! All it takes is a little forethought, along with deliberate and careful action. I used to let the linux installer automatically configure my partitions, now I do it all manually...which is why I rarely have to reinstall my OS because its not how i like it.